# Trying to shorten an otherwise loooong query

Tags: php, mysql, performance

This is kind of simple but not at the same time.

I've got a basic search box into which a user puts in a name.
A name that only consists of `first_name` and `last_name`.
The table has the columns `first_name`, `last_name`, `display_name` where `firs_name` and `last_name` are obviously what the first and last names, and `display_name` is either the concatenation of `first_name` and `last_name` or a preferred name so `William Smith` might have a display name of `Bill Smith`.

The wackyness:

Both first names and last names can be double-names. By that I mean we might have a name like

```
First Name: Anna Maria    Last Name: Smith
First Name: Anna          Last Name: Bo Johnson
First Name: Anna Maria    Last Name: Bo Johnson.
```

so best case scenario, a name would be `Anna Smith` but I've got enough worst case scenarios `Anna Maria Bo Johnson` to have to do this.

When a user searches for `Anna Maria Bo Johnson` I need to run a query that's not aware of which of the 4 "words" is a first or last name, and sadly a double first double last name has 84 combinations like `Anna Bo Maria Johnson`, or `Bo Maria Johnson Anna` etc...

Now My issue is, I dont want my MySQL query to be 84 lines long like this : (3 word name example)

```
SELECT * FROM tablename a
WHERE
    (a.first_name = '$search_term[0]' AND a.last_name = '$search_term[1]') OR      
    (a.first_name = '$search_term[0]' AND a.last_name = '$search_term[2]') OR         
    (a.first_name = '$search_term[0]' AND a.last_name = '$search_term[1] $search_term[2]') OR
    (a.first_name = '$search_term[0]' AND a.last_name = '$search_term[2] $search_term[1]') OR
    (a.first_name = '$search_term[1]' AND a.last_name = '$search_term[0]') OR
    (a.first_name = '$search_term[1]' AND a.last_name = '$search_term[1]') OR     
    (a.first_name = '$search_term[1]' AND a.last_name = '$search_term[0] $search_term[2]') OR
    (a.first_name = '$search_term[1]' AND a.last_name = '$search_term[2] $search_term[0]') OR
    (a.first_name = '$search_term[2]' AND a.last_name = '$search_term[0]') OR
    (a.first_name = '$search_term[2]' AND a.last_name = '$search_term[1]') OR
    (a.first_name = '$search_term[2]' AND a.last_name = '$search_term[0] $search_term[1]') OR
    (a.first_name = '$search_term[2]' AND a.last_name = '$search_term[1] $search_term[0]') OR
    (a.first_name = '$search_term[0] $search_term[1]' AND a.last_name = '$search_term[2]') OR
    (a.first_name = '$search_term[1] $search_term[0]' AND a.last_name = '$search_term[2]') OR
    (a.first_name = '$search_term[0] $search_term[2]' AND a.last_name = '$search_term[1]') OR
    (a.first_name = '$search_term[2] $search_term[0]' AND a.last_name = '$search_term[1]') OR
    (a.first_name = '$search_term[1] $search_term[2]' AND a.last_name = '$search_term[0]') OR
    (a.first_name = '$search_term[2] $search_term[1]' AND a.last_name = '$search_term[0]') OR
    a.display_name = '$search_term[0] $search_term[1] $search_term[2]' OR
    a.display_name = '$search_term[1] $search_term[2] $search_term[0]' OR
    a.display_name = '$search_term[2] $search_term[1] $search_term[0]'
ORDER BY last_name, first_name ASC
```

So what would be a nice quick and more efficient way to write this query out. Basically I need to compare (=) each word against all fields in random single word or group of 2 word combinations.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: In case it's not obvious $search_term[] is an array that was created by  splitting the search term "Anna Maria Bo Johnson" by spaces using explode()

Comment: You could use the `LIKE` operator (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) in the query but then you would get multiple results. Is the point of the search to come up with exactly one result?

Comment: I have a separate query that uses LIKE alongside AND field NOT IN (SELECT field FROM...) which gives me everything except "exact" search result.

Comment: Depending on your MySQL version you could use regex. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN` statement :

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename a 
WHERE concat_ws(' ',a.first_name,a.last_name) IN ('John Smith','Samantha Rose')
```

Comment: So then i just list all my variations into the IN() portion.

Comment: Yes, concat_ws statement permits to create a string with the firstname and lastname from your DB to compare with conditions described in the IN statement.

Comment: This makes alot of sense. I'll give this a go with hopefully some solid results.

Comment: I went with this one, it does the job and saves me from a long long query. I simply generate a string based on the names to fill in the IN() portion of the query. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused on what you want to match. Looking at the query you have, it seems like you'd match Maria Bo Johnson or even Bo Anna. Is that intended?

If so, can you do

```
SELECT * FROM tablename a WHERE
(a.first_name = '$search_term[0]' OR a.first_name = '$search_term[1]' OR
a.first_name = '$search_term[2]' OR a.first_name = '$search_term[3]')
AND
(a.last_name = '$search_term[0]' OR a.last_name = '$search_term[1]' OR
a.last_name = '$search_term[2]' OR a.last_name = '$search_term[3]')
```

(Possibly adding a check that first_name != last_name...)

Comment: Yes, because there are so many variations. The query cannot assume that Anna Maria are both first names and must treat them as part of the first or last name.

Answer (score 0):

Dont explode but concatenise in mysql

```
where concat(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) = '$search_terms' or a.display_name = '$search_terms'
```

and use LIKE if the input might be just a part of the name:

```
where concat(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) LIKE '%$search_terms%' or a.display_name LIKE '%$search_terms%'
```

**edit** if you fear people sometimes starting with last name, sometimes with first name, add 1 more condition:

```
where concat(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) = '$search_terms' or concat(a.last_name, ' ', a.first_name) = '$search_terms' or a.display_name = '$search_terms'
```

Comment: But will this try all variations?
Anna Maria Bo Johnson, 
Anna Bo Maria Johnson, 
Anna Johnson Bo Maria, 
Maria Anna Johnson Bo, 
etc...

Comment: Why would anyone search for a name in a wrong order?

Comment: I'm European, we have a tendency to refer to people as Last Name, First Name so force of habbit may cause a search like Bo Johnson Anna, so i'm just taking precautions.

Comment: @ipixel : i edited my answer. But you might want to strip commas. (You can do that with the replace function.)

Comment: I'm just curisous how this compares first_name last_name to "Anna Maria Bo Johnson". It's 1 space vs 3 spaces it's 2 fields vs 4 choices. the IN() below at least guarantees my providing all the variations. Does this do it itself?

Comment: @ipixel te IN() variant still gives you a complex query with all possible combinations written out full... according to your specifications, people might search "first_names last_names" or "last_names first_names". Both cases are covered with my solution.

Comment: I'll test it out to make sure it does what i need. I'll reply once i've had a chance to confirm. THANKS!

Comment: Sadly this does not work 100%. When i search a name like John Doe Smith or Doe Smith John it works fine, however if i were to search for  Doe John Smith it wont. Now i know you'll aske who would ever lookup Doe John Smith, while with american names it's obviously silly it's not so much when you're looking for let's say an asian name and you're not sure what's the first name or last ex: Yu Sze Ong